# What happens if you call Lester in a place where you automatically get a wanted level?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Like if you are in the military base and you are taking too much heat, so you would want to remove your wanted level. Could you walk around in there no problem or do you instantly get it back? Video or animated GIF proof would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it before in the Military Base, and what happened was it removed it for a second and then came back right away.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have video or Gif proof but I have tried using the 'lower wanted level' option and it worked but the moment I left where I had hid I got the wanted level back and had to run back, So in other words, you can lower your wanted level if you are out of a guards sight but the moment they see you you get it back.

Answer (score 0):

The stars will come right back since the base is "restricted" the wanted stars will never go away unless you use the Blind Eye